# Why are my two ubuntu installs on separate partitions sharing the same apt-get data?

Tags: package-management, partitioning, apt

I have two ubuntu installs on two separate partitions, one Unity and one Gnome-Shell. They both use a common encrypted /home partition. That sort of setup has worked well for me in the past, but for some reason I'm getting a lot of package management problems lately. When I use Software Center on my Unity parition, it shows that I have installed the gnome3 ppa, which is only installed on my other partition. Are these two partitions sharing the same apt-get data now? That can't be right. If so, how can I fix this?

Comment: i got a feeling, that since they share the same /home, they are sharing some configuration files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you can solve your problem moving the following directories

```
~/.config/software-center
~/.cache/software-center
```

somewhere out of your home.

You have two alternatives:

- continue on both installations with the present content of such dirs;
- start with an empty content.

In my opinion the second alternative is recommended, as it will have the same effect of starting *Software Center* for the first time.

Now close *Software Center*, if it is running, and do a preventive backup of such directories, in case something will go wrong.

**First Alternative**

So, to begin with the first alternative, do the following.

Login on the **first** installation and do:

```
# Create a local copy of 'software-center' dirs
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/software-center/{.config,.cache}
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/local/software-center
cp -a ~/.config/software-center /usr/local/software-center/.config/
cp -a ~/.cache/software-center /usr/local/software-center/.cache/
```

Login on the **second** installation and do:

```
# Same as before
# Create a local copy of 'software-center' dirs
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/software-center/{.config,.cache}
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/local/software-center
cp -a ~/.config/software-center /usr/local/software-center/.config/
cp -a ~/.cache/software-center /usr/local/software-center/.cache/
```

The following commands, operating on the HOME, should be executed only on one of the two installations, and they will have effects on both installations.

```
# Remove the original common copy
rm -r ~/.config/software-center
rm -r ~/.cache/software-center

# Link local copy to where 'software-center' expect to find dirs
ln -s /usr/local/software-center/.config/software-center ~/.config/software-center
ln -s /usr/local/software-center/.cache/software-center ~/.cache/software-center
```

Now the two installations points to different versions of the dirs.

**Second Alternative**

Regarding the second alternative, you can substitute the four `cp` commands with two `mkdir`, one for each installation:

```
mkdir /usr/local/software-center/{.config,.cache}/software-center
```

all other commands could rest the same.

I choosed `/usr/local/software-center` as the base dir for the local copies, but you can choose every dir you want, as long as it do not belongs to home.